# Project Euler - Problem 1 Multiples of 3 and 5 (Java)

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I consider myself a beginner at Java but this [question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) was an easy one.  My only concern is if there is a more efficient way to write this program. I'm very open minded.  I don't care how advanced your answer is, I'm willing to learn.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long limit = 1000;

    long sum = sumOfMultiples(3,limit) + sumOfMultiples(5,limit) - sumOfMultiples(15,limit);

}

public static long sumOfMultiples(long number, long limit){
    long sum = 0;        
    long add = number;

    for(; add < limit; add+=number){
        sum += add;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Look at some implementations done by other people. One of the most popular seems to be this [StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137350/euler-program-in-java). It's probably better than just saying the same thing over again.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the inclusion-exclusion principle here…

> ```
> sumOfMultiples(3,limit) + sumOfMultiples(5,limit) - sumOfMultiples(15,limit);
> ```

… which is good.  The name of the function `sumOfMultiples(…)` is pretty clear.  (The only uncertainty is whether it includes or excludes the upper bound.  JavaDoc would help in that regard.)

There is a way to compute `sumOfMultiples()` in constant time.  Since

$$ 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

you can derive a formula for

$$ k + 2k + 3k + \ldots + nk = k \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

Comment: Here is how I changed the method like adviced in the answer: `public static long sumOfMultiples(long number, long limit){ long n = (limit - 1)/number; return number * n * (n+1)/2; }` I tried this method and it is much faster with huge numbers.